# C clone linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I would like to ask how to modify the cloneList function to work properly?
I always want to add a new element to the top of the list. I want Peter still at the top of the cloned list. I can't change the function header

```
typedef struct TEmployee
{
    struct TEmployee *m_Next;
    struct TEmployee *m_Bak;
    char *m_Name;
} TEMPLOYEE;


TEMPLOYEE *newEmployee (const char *name, TEMPLOYEE *next)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *n = (TEMPLOYEE*) malloc(sizeof(*next));
    
    n->m_Name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

    strcpy(n->m_Name, name);
    n->m_Bak = NULL;        
    n->m_Next = next;
    
    return n;
}
 
TEMPLOYEE *cloneList(TEMPLOYEE *src)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *x;
    x = NULL;
    
    TEMPLOYEE *tmp = src;
    while(tmp)
    {
        x = newEmployee(tmp->m_Name, x);
        x->m_Bak = tmp->m_Bak;
        tmp = tmp->m_Next;
    }
    
    return x;
    
}
int main ()
{
    TEMPLOYEE *a, *b;
    a = NULL;
    b = NULL;
    
    a = newEmployee("Peter",a);
    a = newEmployee("John",a);
    ...
    
    b = clone(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your cloneList function as below, so that you can get head node as return value.

```
TEMPLOYEE *cloneList(TEMPLOYEE *src)
{
    TEMPLOYEE *x;
    x = NULL;

    int nCtr=0;
    TEMPLOYEE *head=NULL;

    TEMPLOYEE *tmp = src;
    while(tmp)
    {
        x = newEmployee(tmp->m_Name, tmp->m_Next);  //note the change
        
       x->m_Bak = tmp->m_Bak;

        if(nCtr == 0)
              head = x;

        tmp = tmp->m_Next;

        nCtr++;
    }
    
    return head;  //return the first node
    
}
```